# NestJS [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database (which is being hosted on Heroku) and getting this error:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<My public IP address>", user "<username>", database "<dbname>", SSL off
```

Here's my `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const cfg: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
};

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(cfg)],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Every `DB_*` variable matches corresponding values in Heroku's `Database Credentials`

I think that the problem is somewhere in `TypeORM`, because connecting to the same DB with the same `.env` file values worked in my other application (written in different programming language)

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix the problem, i had to add these lines in my cfg object:

```
ssl: true,
extra: {
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
},
```

With the `ssl: true` option we will have to use SSL cert, which we don't have yet.

The ideal solution is to get a new SSL certificate, but for development this should be enough.

Comment: Man!!! I spent hours struggling with this issue, and this solution finally helped!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and looks like the same dev environment as you.

in my case, I resolved the error from this [Heloku Postgres Connecting in Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js)

I chose the alternative way to omit the ssl configuration as the link says.

on the console of your project path, type the following command.

> heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify

above command is the same as this.
[image]